# Ruby shoes4 package over 1.5GB

Tags: ruby

I've made a small CLI script in ruby to manage a small shop for a friend, but then he wanted me to make a GUI for him, so I looked around and found shoes4.
So, I went and download it, created a small test, and run:

```
./bin/shoes -p swt:jar ./path/to/app.rb
```

and left it to create the package, then I got a warning from system that I'm running low on disc space, so I went to check the jar file, and it was over 1.5GB and still not done packaging... and the code is very small and basic:

```
require 'yaml'
Shoes.app do
button "Add client" do
    filename = ask_open_file
    para File.read(filename)
    clients = YAML.load_file(filename)
    id = clients[clients.length - 1][0].to_i + 1
    name = ask("Enter the client's full name: ")
    items = ask("Enter list of items.")
    patients[id] = ["ID = "+ id.to_s,"Name = "+ pname,"list of items:\n"+ items]
    File.open(filename, 'w') { |f| YAML.dump(clients, f) }
    alert ("Added new patient.")
end
button "Exit" do
    exit()
end
end
```

any idea why this small app is more than 1.5GB?? or did I try to package it wrong way??

Answer (score 0):

The packager will include everything in the directory of your shoes script and below.